# Hibernate4 timestamp with joda time

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jodatime

does any one know about how to implement create & update timestamps with spring mvc4, hibernate4 and joda-time

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
private LocalDateTime created_at;

public void setCreated_at(LocalDateTime created_at) {
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }
```

When i tried in the above way, i got errors

Comment: And what errors did you get? Also naming is preferred in camelCase in Java and not using underscores except for constants.

Comment: Unsupported property type for generator annotation @CreationTimestamp